# How to use post-build actions as build steps in Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Why the post-build actions are not included in conditional build steps? I want to use `Email notification` for a debug build but `Editable Email Notification` for a release build, things like that.

Comment: This can be achieved using the approach described here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614985/conditional-post-build-step-in-jenkins-ideally-without-plugins/26634091#comment59740648_26634091

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Any Build Step Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Any+Build+Step+Plugin), which allows to use publishers as builders and builders as publishers.

Once installed the plugin needs to be enabled on the `Manage Jenkins → Configure System` page. Find the "Conditional buildstep" section there and select `Any build step` from a drop-down (if you want to use builders as publishers then select "Any build step" for Flexible publish section as well).

[image]